# UBER with SSO using uber rides-android-sdk

Tags: uber-api

I'm trying to get data from ALL_TRIPS Scope.  I'm running into a few issues.

1) once I add the Scope.All_Trips to the `.setScopes` I get redirected verse being able to login to obtain the Token, therefore I get the necessary data from the get `CurrentRide()` method.

```
 configuration = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
                .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
                .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI)
                .setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.HISTORY, Scope.PROFILE, Scope.RIDE_WIDGETS, Scope.ALL_TRIPS))
                .setEnvironment(SessionConfiguration.Environment.SANDBOX)
                .build();

validateConfiguration(configuration);
```

> Error: Webpage not available The webpage at
>   Market://details?hl-en&id=com.ubercab&referrer=mat_cli%3

And it goes on and one.

Once i remove the All_TRIPS SCOPE I get the ability to Sign in.

Any help would be great so that I can move forward with getting the details like driver, vehicle, RideID.

```
private void LoadAllTrips(){
    Session session = loginManager.getSession();

    RidesService AllTrips = UberRidesApi.with(session).build().createService();
    AllTrips.getCurrentRide().enqueue(new Callback<Ride>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Ride> call, Response<Ride> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful())
            {
                Toast.makeText(LoginSampleActivity.this, response.body().getRideId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                ApiError error = ErrorParser.parseError(response);
                Toast.makeText(LoginSampleActivity.this, error.getClientErrors().get(0).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Ride> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You're aware that all_trips is a privileged scope? You can auth in your individual account and any developer accounts listed on your app, but for general use you have to be approved: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/scopes  Does that help?

Comment: Thanks Kyle.  yes, i am aware that the all_trips is privilege scope and when i go to production i will make the request as I see that information in the developer dashboard.  I was under the impression that the sandbox endpoint had all the scopes open so that folks can code against. Is that not the case?  I'm still missing something here.  Do i have to activate the sandbox scope?

Comment: Hi Ronkinkjr. Sandbox does not have those scopes "open". You still have to auth your specific account for those scopes.